# Replace "Search" button in Wordpress with a Font Awesome font

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I am using Wordpress 4.0 with Bootstrap 3.0 and I have just included Font Awesome via the functions.php file. Everything is working fine (I've used the icons for social media etc).

Now, I want to change the "Search" button in the sidebar to a Font Awesome icon (a search icon, instead of button+text). The code in the file wp-includes/general-template.php looks like this:

```
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">' . _x( '', 'label' ) . '</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( '', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" title="' . esc_attr_x( '', 'label' ) . '" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="'. esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) .'" />
```

I want just an input field with the icon next to it, like so:

```
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">' . _x( '', 'label' ) . '</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( '', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" title="' . esc_attr_x( '', 'label' ) . '" />
    </label>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

But yeah, this is not working... If I click on the icon, nothing happens. I have tried to put the i class etc into where now is esc_attr_x( 'Search',  but that didn't help either.

Comment: Why do you want to change the default WordPress search icon? If you're rebranding WordPress editing core WordPress files is a terrible idea as all your overwrites will be overwritten as soon as you update WordPress. Instead look into amending the stylesheet, or even use javascript to inject DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "submit" type of input to send the search request. You could do that by putting your icon element instead of the search text, like so:

```
<input type="submit" class="search-submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</input>
```

However, editing WP core files is a very bad idea. You will loose your changes with the next update you do. Instead, make a file called `searchform.php` in your theme folder and put the entire search form there.

Comment: This is not working. Now it is displaying a button with the icon next to it.

Comment: Next thing to try would be adding the relevant classes to the button element instead, like so: `<input type="submit" class="fa fa-search" />`. You might need to apply additional styling to it. Would be easier to test suggestions if you made a fiddle or provided a live link.

Comment: This is invalid markup, the `input` tag is self closing (e.g. `<input type="submit" value="Search" />` )

Answer (score 0):

Just implemented this in a theme I am working on. The most important thing to remember is that there is no reason why you cant change up the HTML for your searchform as you will see:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label>
    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />  
</label>
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
```

I replaced the default wordpress input with the class submit with a button (this way wordpress wont add in it's default submit text). The main thing is the button is a submit type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like so:

```
<input class="search" type="submit" value="&#xf002" >
```

Or

```
<button class="search" type="submit">&#xf002</button>
```

CSS

```
.search{
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
}
```